# How to send notifications in the background of the cordova app?

Tags: cordova, webview, cordova-plugins

I have created a webview application on [Cardova](https://cordova.apache.org/) 10.
My cordova app sends reminders using the [cordova-plugin-local-notification](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) plugin. But the notification does not come if the application is closed (when the application is open, then all notifications come). I tried using the plugin [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) to keep my application from closing and running in the background, but it doesn't work. I also tried using this fork [cordova-plugin-run-in-background](https://bitbucket.org/TheBosZ/cordova-plugin-run-in-background). But it doesn't work either. This is how my code looked like:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadySecond(), false);

function onDeviceReadySecond() {
var bg = window.cordova.plugins.backgroundMode;
bg.setDefaults({
          text: 'App is running in background',
          hidden: false,
          color: '0098D9',
          icon: 'power',
          channelDescription: 'Keep the App running in the background',
          channelName: 'Keep running in background',
          subText: 'Small hint text',
          showWhen: false
      });
bg.enable();

bg.on('activate', function () {
        bg.disableWebViewOptimizations();

    bg.disableBatteryOptimizations();
    alert('eee');
});
}
```

The application does not remain in the background and the alert message does not appear.
I understand that this plugin only works with card version 8, but not with newer ones? This confuses me a little, as I didn't want to work with the old version of Cordova. Maybe there are some other ways not to close the application? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Show us the notification code. Remove the background plugin - it is not needed. I am using the same notification plugin and all works like a charm. Please share how you create a notification

Comment: @Cheese Thank you for not passing by! I run the alert like this:
`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
function onDeviceReady() {;

      cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
       title: 'Hi!',
        text: 'The alert works!',
        sticky: true,
        foreground: true,
        vibrate: true,
        wakeup: true
      });
    };`

Comment: @Cheese The documentation does not specify in detail what the properties are responsible for, so I was guided by logic.

Answer (score 0):

From your provided code snippet, i can see that you are not passing trigger parameter, but in my case ( that works i do ). So i have a thought maybe something is broken in the plugin, and suggest a workaround - pass a trigger parameter, that will be +1-2s from current time.
And also i don't remember why, but i added a priority parameter - maybe i had similar issue.

Steps to try:

1. Try to add priority parameter to your existing code
2. After, try to add trigger parameter
3. Add both

Please reply, i'm also curious about this

Here is my snippet:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: existingId++,
    title: "Hello from notif",
    text: "Yeah this is text",
    trigger: { in: 1, unit: 'second' },
    foreground: true,
    launch: true,
    priority: 2,
});
```

try to play with different variation of trigger

Comment: Thanks for helping!
I've tried changing the priority. This only changes the location of my message in the android notification curtain. I've also tried experimenting with triggers. This only helps to postpone the sending of the notification for any period. And I need the notification to appear in the android as soon as it comes, even if the application is not running.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you receive alerts even if the application is not running? Maybe I didn’t put it that way. I need notifications to come even if the application is not running. When the application is running or minimized, then notifications come, but as soon as I clear it from running, that is, I kill, then notifications stop coming.
I asked again, because when I was surfing the Internet, I found a lot of information that the cordova-plugin-local-notification plugin cannot do this and requires the use of third-party plugins.

Comment: By kill, I don't mean deleting an app from your phone, but simply closing it from an open list.

Comment: I tried to put down the following properties:
`cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: getRandomInt(0, 1000),
        title: "Hello from notif",
        text: "Yeah this is text",
        trigger: { in: 1, unit: 'second' },
        foreground: true,
        launch: true,
        priority: 2,
        wakeup: true,
        groupSummary: true,
        launch: true,
        lockscreen: true
      });`
But nothing helped.

Comment: @de-gard yes, my app is totally closed and it sends the notifications... Hmmm.. strange

Comment: Can you tell me what else the problem might be? Are you checking for android or ios?

Comment: Can you tell me which version of Cordova you have installed? And what version of android or ios do you have?

Comment: I have created my project using Cordova 9, but now i'm on Cordova 10 ( but haven't updated the projects yet ). So the iOS is 5.1.1 and Android 9.0.0

Comment: What plugins do you use in your project?